# MC-Editor при вставке строк, добавляются отступы

Tags: linux, mc

Копирую текст из sublime2, ОС windows (конец строки `\r\n`):

```
path          = ...
charset_table = ...
...
wordforms = ...
stopwords = ...
```

Вставляю в редакторе файлов `MC`, удаленная машина linux, после вставки все строки сдвинуты:

```
path          = ...
  charset_table = ...
    ...
      wordforms = ...
        stopwords = ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартная болезнь MC... Может помочь: Окно редактора -> Настройки -> Общее -> Автоотступ "Вводом", убрать галку.

Comment: Как в окне редактора вызвать `настройки` через hot-key?

Comment: Как и везде, `F9` показывает верхнюю панель.